# QT QGraphicsScene Drawing Arc

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qpainter

I have a question about drawing specific arc on a scene. I have this information about arc:

Starting Koordinates,
Start Angle,
End Angle ,
Radius.

But I can't use them efficently with `QPainter`. Actually I tried `QPainterPath` to use shape to show on `QGraphicsScene` with `addPath("")` but I can't use function properly. My questions are about how to use this infortmation to draw arc and how to show it on my graphic scene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`QGraphicsEllipseItem`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qgraphicsellipseitem.html#details) to add ellipses, circles, and segments/arcs to a `QGraphicsScene`.

Try

```
QGraphicsEllipseItem* item = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(x, y, width, height);
item->setStartAngle(startAngle);
item->setSpanAngle(endAngle - startAngle);
scene->addItem(item);
```

Unfortunately, QGraphicsEllipseItem only supports `QPainter::drawEllipse()` and `QPainter::drawPie()` - the latter can be used to draw arcs, but has the side effect that there is always a line drawn from the start and the end of the arc to the center.

If you require a true arc, you can e.g. subclass `QGraphicsEllipseItem` and override the `paint()` method:

```
class QGraphicsArcItem : public QGraphicsEllipseItem {
public:
    QGraphicsArcItem ( qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0 ) :
        QGraphicsEllipseItem(x, y, width, height, parent) {
    }

protected:
    void paint ( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget) {
        painter->setPen(pen());
        painter->setBrush(brush());
        painter->drawArc(rect(), startAngle(), spanAngle());

//        if (option->state & QStyle::State_Selected)
//            qt_graphicsItem_highlightSelected(this, painter, option);
    }
};
```

You then still need to handle the item highlighting, unfortunately `qt_graphicsItem_highlightSelected` is a static function defined inside the Qt library.